How to navigate a 2 year old saying "stop it" to everyone
My almost 2 year old has just entered the "mine" stage and is having a hard time sharing toys and taking turns.  I understand this is developmentally appropriate for her age and explain turn taking and such to her each time we hear "No, mine."
Recently however I told her when she wants daddy to stop tickling her she should say "Stop" or "Stop it" instead of the usual "No!"
This worked well for the games but now she will tell anyone to "Stop it!" When they walk into a room, if they're on a toy she wanted to use, literally anything and all day long.
How should I approach this?
I have been redirecting her when I can, trying to provide more words for what she's saying.
I will say things like "No, she is doing cooking right now and can't stop. What can you see her cooking?" Or "They are using the slide right now and you would like a turn? Let's wait here for our turn."
Does anyone have any advice?
I've had some family member complain that it's rude and while it does feel that way I know it is just her learning how to use those words and in what context.  Expanding on her sense of self. Experimenting with what she can control.
I don't want to make it worse or solidify her use of the words but I also want her to know she can tell someone to stop touching her for example

You are absolutely on the right track.
At that age, she’s probably in the two-word-sentences stage, and has a very limited vocabulary, so you can’t expect her to be super precise.
Think of her trying to build a complex Lego model with a small supply of bricks - if that’s all you have, that’s what you can use and the results may or may not be recognizable. She’s also figuring out for each new element, both words and phrases, how they can fit into her evolving mental language model. So it makes a lot of sense to (over-)use that new phrase to see how well it fits.
You are offering both new expressions fitting different situations and are modeling the correct usage. That’s exactly how language acquisition for native speakers happens, just keep doing that. Over time, she’ll get better at following the grammar concepts of her language and the toddler speak gets lost. (Not part of your question, but you could note down or record some of these charming words and expressions to preserve the memory.)
If you must explain your child’s behavior to family members (and I see a big “if” here), you can assure them that she’s just working with the bits and pieces of language she has in her toolbox, that her ability to express herself better and more in accordance with the norms of her socio-cultural context will grow fast in the next few months and that she has no intention of being rude. And for those who are still trying to judge, put them to work by having them read to her, sing songs and generally model good language usage.

I agree with the other answer that at this age the child vocabulary is very small, and they may use the same word/phrase to refer to many different things (e.g., calling every women mom/grandma/auntie, referring to every animal with four legs as a dog, etc.) This is something that can be addressed by suggesting appropriate alternatives, although it would naturally go away as the child masters the language.
Furthermore, it is better not to overestimate the gravity of a child saying things like stop it - firstly it is not as bad as go away or get lost. Secondly, with age they will learn even more interesting words, that will make the parents blush even more. Just wait for the first time they say the F-word, after hearing it in a nursery, school or simply in a street.
